# Bosnia during Easter

Tags: balkans, public-holidays, religion, bosnia

I'm looking to go somewhere over the Easter Break (06/04/12 -09/04/12) where I won't be affected by shops, attractions and services such as trains closing, will I be affected by such things in Bosnia over this period?

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Bosnia_and_Herzegovina#Religion) the largest religious group is Islam (40%).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Bosnia (and Herzegovina), the government does something slightly differently, due to the diversity of religion.  In addition to certain public holidays (including Easter), each person is [permitted two working days per year to fulfill their religious needs](http://www.worldtravelguide.net/bosnia-and-herzegovina/public-holidays).  These days are not considered official public holidays, but if taken around other public holidays (Easter, Christmas, Orthodox Christmas) could mean a lot of people are away / their shops are closed then.

Note that [Good Friday and Easter Monday](http://www.addictedtotravel.com/travel-information/when-to-go-to-bosnia-and-herzegovina) are public holidays [according to some sites](http://www.iexplore.com/dmap/Bosnia-Herzegovina/The+Essentials).

As far as trains go, there's no mention on the [booking site for trains](http://www.zfbh.ba/zfbhenx/index.php?option=com_frontpage&Itemid=27) of holidays or Easter.  The online booking can only be done a month in advance, so can't check that.  However, you could email them on [info@zfbh.ba](http://info@zfbh.ba) and ask.

Comment: I assure you that any means of transport are running regularly or, if I remember correctly, as if it was Sunday. Good Friday is usually a working day unless Mark is right with the fact that people usually take some time off during these holidays which I didn't notice that often when it comes to rural (Islam-dominated) places during Easter.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on where you plan to stay in Bosnia, you'll meet predominantly Christians or Muslims.

Easter and Easter Monday are public holidays there so larger cities like [Sarajevo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarajevo) or [Banja Luka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banja_luka) will have shops and monuments closed. Most of the bars, cafes and restaurants will be open and perhaps some smaller shops.

But if you decide to you stay at smaller towns or rural areas where there's mostly Islam followers such as [Travnik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travnik), [Tuzla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuzla) or [Zenica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenica), I believe you won't have any trouble finding an opened establishment of any type. Of course, there will still be some places that are closed not because of the Easter or the day after but because people just like to take the day off.

Answer (score 2):

The Julian calendar Easter (celebrated by Orthodox Christians, ie. Serbs in Bosnia) is April 15th, so at least in the Serbian parts of Bosnia, it will be "business as usual" the weekend before Easter (when you want to visit).